# Stack Overflow sent me an email to congratulate me having access to chess.stackexchange's review queue

Tags: bug, email

I recently got the "access to review queue" privilege on chess.stackexchange.

But the weird thing is Stack Overflow sent me an email to congratulate me, not Stack Exchange or chess.stackexchange
[image: congratulatory email from Stack Overflow]

It's a minor issue, but I think that changing it will fix the inconsistency.